# How to use JOIN in Laravel when two columns of one table refer to one column of another table?

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5.6

I have two table:-

```
A. users table

    |--------------------------------------------------------|
    |  id  |    fname    |     lname     |      deleted      |
    |--------------------------------------------------------|
    |  1   |     Jax     |     Briggs    |         n         |
    |--------------------------------------------------------|
    |  2   |    Juli     |     Briggs    |         y         |
    |--------------------------------------------------------|
    |  1   |     Nacy    |     Blew      |         n         |
    |--------------------------------------------------------|

B. friend table

    |-------------------------------------------------------------|
    |  id  |    user_id    |     receiver_id     |    status      |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------|
    |  1   |       2       |          3          |       0        |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------|
    |  2   |       1       |          3          |       1        |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------|
    |  1   |       2       |          1          |       1        |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I am trying to retrieve the friends of an user using the following query:-

```
"SELECT users.id, users.fname, users.lname FROM users,friend 
 WHERE 
      IF(friend.user_id != $id, friend.user_id = users.id, friend.receiver_id = users.id)
      AND (friend.user_id = $id OR friend.receiver_id = $id)
      AND (friend.status = 1)
      AND (user.deleted = 'n')"
```

If friend.status = 1, this means the receiver has accepted the friend request.
If user.deleted = n, that means the user account has not been deleted

How can I convert the above query into Laravel Eloquent?

I tried to do something like this:-

```
$friendshipQuery    = Friend::select('users.id', 'users.fname', 'users.lname', 'users.email')
                              ->whereRaw('IF(friend.user_id != ' .$id. ', friend.user_id = users.id, friend.receiver_id = users.id)')
                              ->where(array('friend.status' =>  Globals::FR_ACCEPTED)) // status which are accepted
                              ->where(function($query) use ($id){
                                $query->where(array(
                                               'friend.user_id'       => $id        // check whether user id matches sender id 
                                        ))
                                        ->orWhere(array(
                                                'friend.receiver_id'   => $id        // check whether user id matches receiver id 
                                        ));
                                 })
                                ->where('users.deleted', 'n');
```

Somehow, I can't join the two tables because both friend.user_id and friend.receiver_id refer to users.id.

How can I achieve this?

Is there any other way of doing this effectively?

Answer (score 1):

When using Laravel, this can be accomplished as a self-referencing many-to-many relationship between `users` and `users`, using `friends` as the pivot table.

If you're using Laravel's models, define a `User` model, and a `public function friends()` relationship, something to extent of:

```
class User extends Model {
  ...
  public function friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "friends", "user_id", "receiver_id");
  }
}
```

Then with this, you'd be able to do simply:

```
$user = User::with(["friends"])->first();
$friends = $user->friends;
dd($user, $friends);
```

If you needed to filter that query to only show accepted friends, then you'd simply do:

```
$user = User::with(["friends" => function($query){
  $query->where("status", "=", Globals::FR_ACCEPTED);
}])->first();
$friends = $user->friends;
dd($user, $friends);
```

You might even be able to add that `status` check to the end of the relationship to only ever return accepted friends. But either way, Laravel provides some powerful tools for handling this efficiently, so look into using them.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: This function($query) works from database or from web server side?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use a... [join()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) and aliase the tables names to avoid confusion (`u` for user, `f` for friends, `uf` for user's friends)

```
$friendshipQuery = Friend::table('users as u')
                   ->join('friend as f', 'f.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
                   ->join('users as uf', 'f.receiver_id', '=', 'uf.id')
                   ->select('uf.*')
                   ->where('f.status', '1')
                   ->where('uf.deleted', 'n')
                   ->where('u.deleted', 'n')
                   ->where(function($query) use ($id)
                   {
                       $query->where(array('friend.user_id'       => $id))
                             ->orWhere(array('friend.receiver_id' => $id));
                   });
```

By the way, cartesians joins are terrible and deprecated

I would rewrite the SQL query this way

```
SELECT uf.id, uf.fname, uf.lname
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friend f ON u.id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN users uf ON uf.id = f.receiver_id
WHERE (f.user_id = $id OR f.receiver_id = $id)
  AND (f.status = 1)
  AND (uf.deleted = 'n')
  AND (u.deleted = 'n')
```